# ChromiumWebBrowser Disable Right-Click Context Menu VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

Need to disable ChromiumWebBrowser Right-Click Context Menu in VB .Net.

I try many code examples from offical documentation and convert code from C to VB but still can't make it work.

Please if can show me some example code for disable the right click and avoid the drag and drop over ChromiumWebBrowser in vb .Net

Class File

```
Public Class CustomMenuHandler

Public Sub OnBeforeContextMenu(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As CefSharp.IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame, ByVal parameters As IContextMenuParams, ByVal model As IMenuModel)
    model.Clear()
End Sub

Public Function OnContextMenuCommand(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As CefSharp.IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame, ByVal parameters As IContextMenuParams, ByVal commandId As CefMenuCommand, ByVal eventFlags As CefEventFlags) As Boolean
    Return False
End Function

Public Sub OnContextMenuDismissed(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As CefSharp.IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame)

End Sub

End Class
```

Call Class

```
browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("google.com")
browser.MenuHandler = New CustomMenuHandler
panel1.Controls.Add(browser)
```

> Error:
>   Additional information: An object of type 'Project.CustomMenuHandler' cannot be converted to type 'CefSharp.IContextMenuHandler'.

Answer (score 3):

this is my first answer or reply in the community

I searched the same thing more than hours and after that i found a solution

So you want first implement the IContextMenuHandler

After that you want to implement IContextMenuHandler after every function

```
Imports System
Imports CefSharp

Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class MyCustomMenuHandler
Implements IContextMenuHandler

Public Sub OnBeforeContextMenu(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame, ByVal parameters As IContextMenuParams, ByVal model As IMenuModel) Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnBeforeContextMenu
    model.Clear()
End Sub

Public Function OnContextMenuCommand(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame, ByVal parameters As IContextMenuParams, ByVal commandId As CefMenuCommand, ByVal eventFlags As CefEventFlags) As Boolean Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuCommand
    Return False
End Function


Public Sub OnContextMenuDismissed(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame) Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuDismissed
End Sub

Public Function RunContextMenu(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame, ByVal parameters As IContextMenuParams, ByVal model As IMenuModel, ByVal callback As IRunContextMenuCallback) As Boolean Implements IContextMenuHandler.RunContextMenu
    Return False
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Calling model.Clear is how to disable the menu.

Comment: Yea i know but i provided him a way to edit the menu :D

Comment: The question asks for how to disable the menu though. Not edit the menu.

Comment: what ever i gave him an another option

Comment: It still doesn't answer the actual question. Anyone else experiencing the same problem needs to understand this answer won't disable the context menu. If you were looking for a way to disable the context menu and you came across this answer that doesn't actually disable the context menu  how helpful would you find that?

Comment: thanks for devoting :D - As i mentioned before this is my first reply or answer - this what i really deserve, looks that this community don't read everything, btw at least i fixed the implements problem, that needs it to disable

Comment: I read your answer in full and I'm attempting to provide constructive criticism. I'm downviting as the answer doesn't exactly match the question. It's nothing personal. The question actually shows the code required to disable the menu,  it just doesn't implement the interface. Improve your answer and I'll happily change my vote.

Comment: thanks for noticing me,i know its not personal :D - I edited it - , i am new to community and i want to know more about it so i can avoide any mistake

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `CustomMenuHandler` class should implement the required interface, as follows :

```
Public Class CustomMenuHandler implements IContextMenuHandler
```

This would fix the issue for you. In case you are looking for alternatives, you can simply capture the `MouseDown` event, check if the key pressed in the mouse is the right-mouse key (`MouseButton.Right`) and handle the click event with `e.Handled = True`;

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Public Class CustomMenuHandler implements IContextMenuHandler = Show "End of instruction expected" I am Working on Visual Studio 2015 (Vb.Net)

Comment: Implementing the interface is correct. The suggested alternative won't work though as `Chromium` swallows all mouse related messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution. Call it with `Browser.MenuHandler = New CustomMenuHandler()`:

```
Imports System
Imports CefSharp

Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class CustomMenuHandler
    Implements CefSharp.IContextMenuHandler
    Public Sub OnBeforeContextMenu(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame, ByVal parameters As IContextMenuParams, ByVal model As IMenuModel) Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnBeforeContextMenu
        model.Clear()
    End Sub
    Public Function OnContextMenuCommand(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame, ByVal parameters As IContextMenuParams, ByVal commandId As CefMenuCommand, ByVal eventFlags As CefEventFlags) As Boolean Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuCommand
        Return False
    End Function
    Public Sub OnContextMenuDismissed(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame) Implements IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuDismissed
    End Sub

    Public Function RunContextMenu(ByVal browserControl As IWebBrowser, ByVal browser As IBrowser, ByVal frame As IFrame, ByVal parameters As IContextMenuParams, ByVal model As IMenuModel, ByVal callback As IRunContextMenuCallback) As Boolean Implements IContextMenuHandler.RunContextMenu
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```